# Notification using GCM

Tags: android, push-notification

I am trying to open the detail page in my app by clicking on the notification in the Android app, but on each notification click, it shows the same data, that is the data of the last notification. I get some values from a server request &  these are received properly. The only the problem is navigation to the detail page with the proper ID. Here is what I have tried:

```
package com.abc;
import static com.abc.Settings.SENDER_ID;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;


public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyTag";
    static int i=0,j=0,k=0,l=0,m=0;
    Operation op=new Operation();
    Activity activity;

    public GCMIntentService() 
    {
        super(SENDER_ID);  string. 
    }
    @Override

    protected void onRegistered(Context context,String registrationId) 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Device registered :"+registrationId);

        op.register(getApplicationContext(), Settings.name, Settings.email, registrationId,Settings.staff_id);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Device unregistered :"+registrationId);

        op.unregister(getApplicationContext(), registrationId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) 
    { 

        Log.d("In onMessage","In onMessage");

       String data = intent.getExtras().getString("message");//TOTAL ARRAY
       String hash = intent.getExtras().getString("hash");
       String title_data = intent.getExtras().getString("event");
       String client_id = intent.getExtras().getString("client_id");
       String department_id = intent.getExtras().getString("department_id");
       String ticket_id = intent.getExtras().getString("ticket_id");

       String message=getMessage(title_data);

       Log.d(TAG, "message :"+message);
       String id = null ,title = null;

      generateNotification(getApplicationContext(),message,title,id,title_data,hash,client_id,department_id,ticket_id);


    }

    // return text according to event 
    private String getMessage(String event) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String message = null;
        if(event.equals("1"))
        {message=(String)getText(R.string.new_ticket_client);}
        else if(event.equals("3"))
        {message=(String)getText(R.string.reply_ticket_client);}
        else if(event.equals("4"))
        {message=(String)getText(R.string.client_added);}
        else if(event.equals("5"))
        {message=(String)getText(R.string.new_blab);}
        else if(event.equals("6"))
        {message=(String)getText(R.string.blab_comment);}
        return message;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) 
    {

    }
    // On receiving an error
    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Received error: " + errorId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG,"Received error: " + errorId);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Received recoverable error: " + errorId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG,"Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }
   // method to generate a notification
    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message,String title,String id,String event,String hash,String client_id,String department_id,String ticket_id) 
    {

            int icon = R.drawable.app_icon;
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Intent notificationIntent = null;

            if(event.equals("1"))
            {
                 i++;
                try{


                String msg="New ticket created by client ("+i+")";
                notificationIntent = new Intent(context,Tabs.class);
                notificationIntent.putExtra("filter_id","&vis_filter_id=1");        
                notificationIntent.putExtra("title",(String)context.getString(R.string.inbox));
                notificationIntent.putExtra("client_id",client_id);
                notificationIntent.putExtra("dept_id",department_id);
                notificationIntent.putExtra("set_queue","no");
                notificationIntent.putExtra("Ticket_hash",hash);
                notificationIntent.putExtra("Ticket_id",ticket_id);  
                notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

               PendingIntent pending_intent =PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
               //PendingIntent pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,   notificationIntent, 0);
               // PendingIntent pending_intent =PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, i);

                      NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setWhen(time)
                        .setContentTitle((String)context.getString(R.string.app_name))  
                        .setContentText(msg)
                        .setSmallIcon(icon)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)                    
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS| Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE| Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                        .setContentIntent(pending_intent); 

                      Notification notification=notificationBuilder.build();
                      notificationManager.notify(i, notification);

               // notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.d("Exception in Notification : ",e.toString());
                }
            }


    }
}
```

Comment: You can use this URL for notification guide: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html

Comment: Try this 
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this

```
String x_id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
notificationIntent.putExtra("x_id", x_id );
notificationIntent.setAction(x_id);
```

Comment: notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);      is not working

Comment: String x_id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
notificationIntent.putExtra("x_id", x_id );
notificationIntent.setAction(x_id);Its working properly , but I dont understand wt it actually do ?